# Custom Sitecore index configuration for Solr implementation

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, sitecore

I have a custom index in Sitecore that I created originally to use Lucene. For the sake of this question let's call that index "News". I am converting all Lucene indexes to Solr. There is a separate Solr core for each sitecore index including the News index. All the indexes are rebuilding, and I am seeing documents in Solr for the default OOTB Sitecore indexes, but no documents are being added to the News Core in Solr. The schema that I'm using for the News core was generated via Sitecore's schema generation tool in the control panel. Does this schema need to be modified to reflect the fields that I've specified in the Sitecore Index configuration file?

```xml
<sitecore>
 <contentSearch>
  <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="News" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>

        <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />

        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">

          <documentOptions ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/documentOptions">

            <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>

            <!-- Included templates -->
            <include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate">
              <template1>{3139428E-AF1E-4678-916F-08B2A44453E7}</template1>
              <template2>{C74B549F-9A1D-4FE3-8A3E-F4CF778DCD3C}</template2>
              <template3>{E29A6486-5721-4FAA-A5F7-B3CC3AD81DB1}</template3>
              <template4>{D5ED7AB3-D466-4CED-A739-B55D9E39FAE7}</template4>
              <template5>{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}</template5>
              <template6>{9E349B58-3F90-450C-A7EE-B904AC59D14B}</template6>
            </include>
          </documentOptions>
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
              <field fieldName="_uniqueid" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="article" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="author" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="author credentials" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="date" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.DateTime" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="degree" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="graduation year" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
             <field fieldName="location" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="navigation title" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="page abstract" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="parentname" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="school" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="text" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
             <field fieldName="url" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
              <field fieldName="value" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              </field>
            </fieldNames>
            <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="image" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="general link" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
            </fieldTypes>
          </fieldMap>
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="external_link" stored="true" returnType="System.String">mydll.ExternalLink, mydll</field>
            <field fieldName="image" stored="true" returnType="System.String">mydll.ComputedFields.Image, mydll</field>
            <field fieldName="terms" stored="true" returnType="System.String">mydll.ComputedFields.Terms, mydll</field>
            <field fieldName="url" stored="true" returnType="System.String">mydll.ComputedFields.Url, mydll</field>
            <field fieldName="parentname" stored="true" returnType="System.String">mydll.ComputedFields.ParentName, mydll</field>
          </fields>

        </configuration>

        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
        </strategies>
        <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
            <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ModificationCountCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <Limit>300</Limit>
            </policy>
          </policies>
        </commitPolicyExecutor>

        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>

        <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
        <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>

      </index>
    </indexes>
   </configuration>
  </contentSearch>
 </sitecore>
```

Comment: The problem will not be in the schema but probably in the index config. There are some differences between Lucene and Solr for custom indexes. Can you share that to provide better help?

Comment: @Gatogordo I've edited the answer to show the custom configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to change:

- rename your index to "news" (I had some issues when using capitals in index names)
- move the `indexAllFields` outside the `documentOptions` (it has to be under `configuration` with Solr - so on the same level as the documentOptions)
- add `ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap` to your `fieldMap` element.
- redo your `fieldMap` - you are using a Lucene fieldMap here. You can check the default Solr config for an example on how to do this with Solr - it would look more like `<field fieldName="article" returnType="string" />` and so on..
- redo your `fieldTypes` as that is also still referring to Lucene

Best thing to do is put the default Solr configuration next to your custom one to have an example on how to set all elements.

Comment: thanks! My config file was all messed up. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to resolve this